# UPDATE Blocking SELECT Of Unrelated Rows

Tags: sql-server

I have `TableA` with `Col1` as the primary key. I am running the following transaction without committing it (for test purposes).

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE TableA
SET Col3 = 0
WHERE Col2 = 'AAA'
```

In the meanwhile, I run the following query and see that it waits on the first transaction to complete.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE Col2 = 'BBB'
```

But the following query returns the results immediately:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE Col1 = '1'
```

So I thought that the second query might need to read rows that have exclusive locks put by the first transaction in order to select rows with `Col2 = 'BBB'`. That's why then I tried to index `Col2` so that a table seek will not be necessary but that did not work either. Second query still waits on the first transaction.

What should be done to prevent `SELECT` from blocking (except the use of `NOLOCK`).

P.S: Transaction isolation level is "Read Committed".

Comment: Do you have indexes on col1 and col3? How many rows total in the table?  Did you check what resources (locks) 2nd query is waiting on?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide Col1 is the primary key, so it is implicitly indexed. I have no index on Col3.

Answer (score 2):

I might have to modify this answer once you provide more information based on my comment.

For now follow this example.  I am using SQL 2016, SP1.

```
--Creating table
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableA
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
      [col1] [int] NULL,
      [col2] [nchar](10) NULL,
      [col3] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
```

Inserting data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableA]
           VALUES (10, 'AAA', 11),
                  (12, 'BBB', 13),
                  (14, 'CCC', 15)
```

Session ID 65 running this.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE TableA
SET Col3 = 0
WHERE Col2 = N'AAA'
```

Session ID 66 running this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE Col2 = N'BBB'
```

Looking at the locks held by both session. Session 65 is holding an exclusive lock on file id:1, page id:488 and slot id=0, shared lock is requested on the same resource by session 66 and is waiting.

[image]

Running the 2nd query and looking at the actual execution plan it is doing a table scan and because of your isolation level reading requires a shared lock to prevent any update or delete on the same row.

[image]

Creating an index on col2 does not change the behavior in my case because of number of rows.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_TableA_col2] ON [dbo].[TableA]
(
    [col2] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

GO
```

After I inserted 3000+ rows I can get a index seek and session 66 will not wait for the session 65 anymore.

[image]

**Why did your 3rd query ran without waiting:** I can answer that once you provide more information.

Comment: I did provide an answer to your comment on the original post. What I understand from your answer is that for the WHERE Col2 = 'BBB' query, the query planner chooses to do a table scan even though there is a nonclustered index on Col3. But when the number of rows is large, it will choose to do an index scan so there will not be a problem. Maybe the reason WHERE Col1 = '1' is not blocked is that it is the primary key and query planner does an index scan regardless of the number of rows?

Comment: I do not know for sure but can test that. Please add your table defination and what is the total number of rows you are testing with.